# Clicking a button with Python to load HTML

Tags: python, html, youtube, web-scraping

I'm making a python script that scrapes information from Youtube playlists.

My issue is that my script does not work for playlists containing 100+ videos as Youtube requires that you click a 'Load more' button at the bottom of the page (see code and image below) in order to load more of the playlist.

My question is how can I click this button using Python in order to load the rest of the page?

[image]

```
<button class="yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-default load-more-button yt-uix-load-more browse-items-load-more-button" type="button" onclick=";return false;" aria-label="Load more
" data-uix-load-more-target-id="pl-load-more-destination" data-uix-load-more-href="/browse_ajax?    action_continuation=1&amp;continuation=4qmFsgIuEiRWTFBMQjZKLXhzOVhod0IyRHY2ZV9rR0t4Z2xEOVNVdDBVSmQaBkNHVSUzRA%253D%253D"><span class="yt-uix-button-content">  <span     class="load-more-loading hid">
  <span class="yt-spinner">
  <span title="Loading icon" class="yt-spinner-img  yt-sprite"></span>

Loading...
  </span>

  </span>
  <span class="load-more-text">
    Load more

  </span>
</span></button>
```

Comment: Selenium could be used to automate pressing the button.  There is an example of doing this to download images from google search at https://simplypython.wordpress.com/2015/05/18/saving-images-from-google-search-using-selenium-and-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually clicking a button makes a form to be submitted. This form submission is an HTTP POST request. I've checked youtube (using Chrome dev-tools) with clicking to the `next` button and found it being `XHR GET HTTP` request. See picture below: 
[image]

So after you initially get a page, you might load more (pages 2,3 etc.) thru requesting: 
`https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=<search term>&page=2&spf=navigate`
instead of `page=2` you set next page number in row, ex. `page=3` etc.

The response will be a nice formatted JSON with all info you need.